# Problema en referencia cruzada dinámica en Northwind

Tags: sql, sql-server, vistas

Tengo una confusión al establecer una referencia cruzada dinámica con la lista de los productos en Northwind.

El punto es establecer un puntaje a los 3 productos más vendidos por cada mes en el año 1997.

```
create view vistaProductosPts
as
select ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by Mes Order By Cantidad asc) as Pts, 
Producto, Mes from
(select * from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by MONTH(O.OrderDate) Order By 
SUM(D.Quantity) desc) as Num, P.ProductName as Producto, Month(O.OrderDate)     
as Mes, SUM(D.Quantity) as Cantidad
from Orders O inner join [Order Details] D on O.OrderID = D.OrderID inner 
join 
Products P on D.ProductID = P.ProductID
where YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 1997
Group By P.ProductName, MONTH(O.OrderDate)) as X
where Num <= 3) as Y
```

Así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Geitost es el producto más vendido de Enero(3 puntos), Raclette el 2do y así

Y tengo una referencia cruzada dinámica que establece cada producto en las columnas y las filas con los meses y sus puntajes, más una ultima fila con el total sumado:

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo un error al ejecutar la sentencia SQL con la referencia cruzada dinámica:

```
Declare @productos nvarchar(4000) 
set @productos = ''
Select @productos = @productos + 'isnull([' +T.Producto+ '],0),' from
(Select distinct P.ProductName as Producto from Orders O inner join [Order 
Details] D on O.OrderID = D.OrderID inner join Products P on D.ProductID = 
P.ProductID where YEAR(O.OrderDate) = 1997
                                                     ) as T 
set @productos = LEFT(@productos, LEN(@productos) - 1)

select @productos

Declare @sentencia as nvarchar(4000)
set @sentencia = concat('Select * from vistaProductosPts PIVOT 
(SUM(Cantidad) as Total for Producto in (',@productos,')) PVT')
Execute @sentencia
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué debo hacer para que se ejecute correctamente? De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas poner `Execute (@Sentencia)` con paréntesis. De otra forma, está buscando un procedimiento almacenado con el nombre igual al valor de @Sentencia.

Sería importante que te acostumbraras a usar `sp_executesql` para prevenir problemas de inyección de SQL mediante la parametrización de tus consultas dinámicas. El código cambia muy poco

```
Execute sp_executesql @Sentencia --, @Params, @Param1, @Param2, ..., @ParamN
```